# Xjc generating 1000+ classes for fpml schema

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, xjc

1. I have xml based on fpml schema.
2. Used  **xjc**  command line tool to generate corresponding pojo classes.
3. Then I am using  **JAXB**  to unmarshal xml into java objects.
   I converted this to objects as an intermediate step because then it is easy to read values of some fields.
4. But problem is fpml schema generated ~1200 classes.
   so I am not sure if this is correct approach as jar size will also increase.

**My problem statement** : convert one xml based on one schema to another xml based on another schema. Both involves fpml. While populating another xml I need to validate few fields from database.

please give me suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Data binding technologies such as JAXB work fine for simple cases, but when the schema is large, complex, or frequently changing, they become quite unwieldy, as you have discovered.

This is a task for XSLT. Use schema-aware XSLT if possible, because it makes your stylesheet easier to debug.

Comment: Thanks Michael, But I need to write external validations as well like validating fields using DB before populating into another xml.                                     Again writing xslt for such a long file with complex nested elements with enum values would be easier ?

Comment: If I were giving professional consultancy then I wouldn't dream of advising on choice of technology or application architecture with so little information about your requirements. I would look into it much more carefully, and then -- probably -- tell you to use XSLT!